# How do I import JSX into .tsx file (not in React)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx, stenciljs

I am **not using React**.
I am using **Stenciljs**.

I have the following **.tsx** file:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() message: string;

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.message}</div>);
  }
}
```

I want to do this instead:

```
import myTemplate from '../my-template.??';

export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() message: string;

  render() {
    return (myTemplate);
  }
}
```

with `../my-template.??` containing:

```
<div>{this.message}</div>
```

Is it possible and how ? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can absolutely do this, there are just a couple of things you need to tidy up:

**Main file**

```
import { Template } from '../template'; // No need for file extension but we're using a named export so we need the curly braces around 'Template'

export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() message: string;

  render() {
    return ( // You don't technically need the parentheses here as you're just returning one thing
      <Template /> // When outputting an imported component, it goes in angle brackets and the backslash closes it like an HTML element
    )
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
import React from 'react';  // template needs React

export const Template = () => { // defining the export in this way is known as a named export
  return (
    <p>A message here</p>
  )
}
```

Okay, so that's going to get you a message output which is from your template.  However, you were asking about passing a message *to* that template for it to output.  That's totally easy as well - you just need to get some props in there.  Here is the modified version of the above:

**Main file**

```
import { Template } from '../template';

export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() message: string;

  render() {
    return (           
      <Template messageToOutput={message} /> // The first argument is the name of the prop, the second is the variable you defined above
    )
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
import React from 'react';

export const Template = (props) => { // props are received here
  return (
    <p>{props.messageToOutput}</p> // props are used here
  )
}
```

That's how you pass data around in React - hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for you answer but it implies I am in a React context. I am not. I use a library called Stencil.js I was under the impressions that jsx is not "linked" to React but rather to Typescript? Do I absolutely need React??

Comment: For Stencil projects, you can just remove the `import React` line and it will work.

Comment: oh wow, really? ok I'll give it a try and get back to you thanks!